# Best practices for throttling by restricting resource pools in multi tier application?

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, architecture, n-tier-architecture

What is the best practice for setting resource pools in a multi tier application?

The call coming from the client (app, web portal) follows this path: WAF, Apache, presentation tier (AEM), a service gate way, a JEE backend server, backend DB.

Where should we throttle calls? At the very top? (E.g. Apache max connections) Or throttle at each layer (Apache, presentation tier max workers, service gate way max connections, JEE max threads/max JDBC connections)?

Happy for any good literature on this issue.

Comment: In a typical AEM project, you implement throttling with proper caching and offloading. If that doesn't work, you have to look at horizontal and vertical scaling. Most of AEM is based on internal queues so things are throttled by design of the architecture. Might be helpful to understand the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: We are analysing the resources allocated throughout the architecture. Some calls bypass AEM (e.g. API cals from the app, that go directly to the service gate way and into the backend). My problem is, that I'm not sure what the best practices for setting connection pools, thread pools etc. is. Do you throttle at the very front? Or at every hop?

Comment: In general, if a resource requires throttling then you throttle it, otherwise throttling becomes a bottleneck. In practice, you find the bottlenecks and try to come up with the best pattern for scaling the resource's usage without impacting the whole stack. This is a broader topic.